# Efficient way to calculate byte length of a character, depending on the encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding, character, byte

What's the most efficient way to calculate the byte length of a character, taking the character encoding into account? The encoding would be only known during runtime. In UTF-8 for example the characters have a variable byte length, so each character needs to be determined individually. As far now I've come up with this:

```
char c = getCharSomehow();
String encoding = getEncodingSomehow();
// ...
int length = new String(new char[] { c }).getBytes(encoding).length;
```

But this is clumsy and inefficient in a loop since a `new String` needs to be created everytime. I can't find other and more efficient ways in the Java API. There's a [`String#valueOf(char)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29), but according its source it does basically the same as above. I imagine that this can be done with bitwise operations like bit shifting, but that's my weak point and I'm unsure how to take the encoding into account here :)

<sub>*If you question the need for this, check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725897/reverse-massive-text-file-in-java/2725993#2725993).*</sub>

---

**Update:** the answer from [@Bkkbrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726071/efficient-way-to-calculate-byte-length-of-a-character-depending-on-the-encoding/2726284#2726284) is technically the most efficient:

```
char c = getCharSomehow();
String encoding = getEncodingSomehow();
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName(encoding).newEncoder();
// ...
int length = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(new char[] { c })).limit();
```

However as [@Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) pointed out, there are more problems with this. There may for example be combined/surrogate characters which needs to be taken into account as well. But that's another problem which needs to be solved in the step *before* this step.

Comment: Using the above did you have performance problems? Do you always want to use UTF-8?

Comment: The example was indeed a bit misleading, but actually the encoding can only be determined during runtime. I've updated the question. After all, this doesn't look like to be an easy task though.

Comment: this is completely wrong and so is bkkbrad's answer.  It's actually quite frightening to see so many people completely wrong on that one (+1 only to bkail's answer).  A Java *char* does **not**, I repeat **A JAVA CHAR DOES NOT** represent a character anymore since Java 1.4 / Unicode 3.1.  *String.value(char)* and wrapping "char"* and whatnots are all methods from the nineties.  The world moved on and it's been a very long time that Unicode has more than 65 536 codepoints.  Use "int", get "char" out of your mind because Java char is broken beyond repair.  ♩   ♩  ♩    ♩

Comment: @Wizard: cool down :) Take a break.

Comment: I added a new solution based on Wizard's pointed criticism.

Comment: For anyone looking for a way to calculate a String bytes size in UTF-8 you can use Guava's Utf8.encodedLength(string)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [CharsetEncoder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) and reuse a [CharBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html) as input and a [ByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) as output.

On my system, the following code takes 25 seconds to encode 100,000 single characters:

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
char[] array = new char[1];
for (int reps = 0; reps < 10000; reps++) {
    for (array[0] = 0; array[0] < 10000; array[0]++) {
        int len = new String(array).getBytes(utf8).length;
    }
}
```

However, the following code does the same thing in under 4 seconds:

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetEncoder encoder = utf8.newEncoder();
char[] array = new char[1];
CharBuffer input = CharBuffer.wrap(array);
ByteBuffer output = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
for (int reps = 0; reps < 10000; reps++) {
    for (array[0] = 0; array[0] < 10000; array[0]++) {
        output.clear();
        input.clear();
        encoder.encode(input, output, false);
        int len = output.position();
    }
}
```

**Edit:  Why do haters gotta hate?**

Here's a solution that reads from a CharBuffer and keeps track of [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_pair):

```
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetEncoder encoder = utf8.newEncoder();
CharBuffer input = //allocate in some way, or pass as parameter
ByteBuffer output = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);

int limit = input.limit();
while(input.position() < limit) {
    output.clear();
    input.mark();
    input.limit(Math.max(input.position() + 2, input.capacity()));
    if (Character.isHighSurrogate(input.get()) && !Character.isLowSurrogate(input.get())) {
        //Malformed surrogate pair; do something!
    }
    input.limit(input.position());
    input.reset();
    encoder.encode(input, output, false);
    int encodedLen = output.position();
}
```

Comment: Technically, this is the best answer as far (if you replace `position()` by `limit()`). This is indeed much efficienter.

Comment: @Bkkbrad: A Java char is totally inadequate since 1993 or so to represent a Unicode character, when Unicode moved to 1.1 and had more than 65 536 codepoints.  The method to use to get a character in Java is String's *codePointAt(..)* which correctly returns an *int*.  Java *char* is, well, utterly broken.  (200 KLOC codebase here and we're using Java char, well... **zero** times).

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: I added a solution to keep track of surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that an encoding scheme could encode a given character as a variable number of bytes, depending on what comes before and after it in the character sequence.  The byte length you get from encoding a single character String is therefore not the whole answer.

(For example, you could theoretically receive a baudot / teletype characters encoded as 4 characters every 3 bytes, or you could theoretically treat a UTF-16 + a stream compressor as an encoding scheme.  Yes, it is all a bit implausible, but ...)

Comment: Yes, good point, the surrogate characters has indeed to be taken into account sooner or later.

Answer (score 3):

If you can guarantee that the input is well-formed UTF-8, then there's no reason to find code points at all.  One of the strengths of UTF-8 is that you can detect the start of a code point from any position in the string.  Simply search backwards until you find a byte such that (b & 0xc0) != 0x80, and you've found another character.  Since a UTF-8 encoded code point is always 6 bytes or less, you can copy the intermediate bytes into a fixed-length buffer.

Edit: I forgot to mention, even if you don't go with this strategy, it is not sufficient to use a Java "char" to store arbitrary code points since code point values can exceed 0xffff.  You need to store code points in an "int".

Comment: Very good tip. Unfortunately there's likely no 100% guarantee.

Comment: @bkail: +1 to you for you're the only one in this thread to mention that a Java *char* cannot store arbitrary codepoints and that *int* should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("string").limit();` Might be a bit more efficient, maybe not.

Comment: This still require a `String` as input.