# Insert non-English string into UTF-8 Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, utf-8, eclipselink

I have a Oracle and it's encoding is UTF-8. When I insert some non-English string into it, I'll get ORA-12899. I think the reason is some non-English needs 3 bytes in UTF-8 system.

The simplest solution is to extend the length of Oracle. I want to trim the string and I can't find a single solution to trim the string. Are there any suggestions? I tried to get the byte length but the value is not for UTF-8.

Comment: Which data type is the column? Also, for length try `LENGTHB` (which gives the length in bytes) instead of `LENGTH` (which gives the length in characters).

Comment: If you want to do the same thing as in @EgorSkriptunoff's answer, but in Java, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726071/efficient-way-to-calculate-byte-length-of-a-character-depending-on-the-encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lengthb()` to get length in bytes. Truncate your string until it fits into column:

```
while lengthb(x) > column_length_in_bytes loop
  x := substr(x, 1, length(x)-1);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String truncatedUTF8( String input, int maxBytesInUTF8 ) {
    if( input.length() * 4 <= maxBytesInUTF8 ) {
        return input;
    }
    int max = 0, i;
    boolean lastSurrogate = false;
    for( i = 0; i < input.length() && max <= maxBytesInUTF8; ++i ) {
        int cc = Character.codePointAt(input, i);
        lastSurrogate = false;
        if (cc <= 0x7F) {
            max++; 
        } else if (cc <= 0x7FF) {
            max += 2; 
        } else if (cc <= 0xFFFF) {
            max += 3;
        } else if (cc <= 0x10FFFF) {
            lastSurrogate = true;
            max += 4;
            i++;
        }    
    }

    if( max < maxBytesInUTF8 ) {
        return input;
    }
    if( max > maxBytesInUTF8) {
        i--;
        if( lastSurrogate ) i--;
    }

    if( i - 1 >= input.length() && 
        !Character.isSurrogatePair(input.charAt(i-2), input.charAt(i-1)) &&
        Character.isSurrogate(input.charAt(i-1))) {
        i--;
    }

    return input.substring(0, i);
}

System.out.println(truncatedUTF8("äää", 5));
//"ää" because "äää" takes 6 bytes and "ää" takes 4
```